# UpdatePanel with Panel.DefaultButton set, can't type in textbox after postback in IE8

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I just created a new page and placed only 4 basic controls on it like this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1"
                runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then load the page and do these steps:

1. Click in the textbox
2. Press the ENTER key - this will cause the button to be clicked since it is the default button for the panel
3. Click back in the textbox
4. Press the ENTER key again

At this point I cannot type anything in the textbox.

I believe it must have something to do with keypress handler that Panel.DefaultButton creates.  For example, if it was always returning false, that would make it so all keystrokes would be ignored.

This only happes with IE8 when not in compatibility mode.  Works fine in Chrome, FireFox, and IE8 in compatibility mode.

This seems like a common thing developers would do, have a textbox and button inside an update panel, with a default button set... yet, I haven't found very many topics discussing this issue, and none of the solutions seem robust at all.  I wouldn't think for something so basic I would need to resort to hacks like having a timer that changes the focus to another control and then back.

**Does anyone have a robust fix for this?**  I'm using ASP.NET 3.5, but not easy for me to upgrade to 4.0 right now.

Comment: Adding OnClientClick="this.focus();" to the button fixes the issue, but I'll wait to see if anyone has a better answer and/or more info before posting this as my answer.  It appears IE8 might have some bug related to generating a button click event when the button does not have the focus.  Or maybe ASP.NET/IE8 specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is the way asp.net implements the default button handler, as a workaround you need to add the following JS method to your aspx page :

```
function ResetDefaultFired()
 {
     __defaultFired = false;
 }
```

and your client click in the button should be: OnClientClick=”ResetDefaultFired”

This method resets the __defaultFired flag that is used internally to avoid multiple clicks execution in the default button handler.For further exaplanation check:
http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2008/07/07/update-panel-and-default-button-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue several times in several browsers. The solution that typically works for me is to set the `ScriptManager`'s `EnablePartialRendering` attribute to `false`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

I hope this helps!

Good luck, and happy coding! :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but doesn't this disable the asynchronous AJAX UpdatePanel updates?

Comment: @Sam - you are correct, but I would clarify by rephrasing it to say that it disables the ability to asynchronously update the parts of the page in UpdatePanels. That aside, the issue in the OP was presenting after a PostBack. I believe that I posted this answer because, in general, mixing AJAX forms and postbacks should be avoided. Regardless, I should have included that caveat as a disclosure.